# adding json object in json array and agian json array in json object from sqlite

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I m new to android i want to get `json` format  like below

[here is image what  i want json output](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9qgugNyvGRiVGUySWU3eEpRajA)

here is code

```
 public JSONObject getjsondataofcart(){
    JSONObject modelList = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray myara   = new JSONArray();
    String query = "select * from "+ cart_table;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    try {

      if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

          data.put("id", cursor.getInt(1));
          data.put("qty", cursor.getInt(2));
          data.put("amount", cursor.getInt(7));
          data.put("tax_id","0");
          data.put("sub_total", cursor.getInt(6));
          myara.put(data);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        modelList.put("product_detail",myara);
      }
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
    }

    return modelList;
  }
```

I got out put as below:

[here is what i got](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9qgugNyvGRiV2ZrVlp3TUlIM3M)

Comment: So what you need? There is no difference in what you get and what you want

Comment: Its a hometask ??

Comment: Congratulations! You have got the result what you want :)

Comment: just second i posted same image let me edit what  i got

Comment: i can't see any difference in both images

Comment: i edited question. i am getting same object in array not diffrent one.

Comment: check and try chetan's answer below. I think that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
```

Move above line inside of do-while loop like below

```
try {

  if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
      JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
      data.put("id", cursor.getInt(1));
      data.put("qty", cursor.getInt(2));
      data.put("amount", cursor.getInt(7));
      data.put("tax_id","0");
      data.put("sub_total", cursor.getInt(6));
      myara.put(data);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    modelList.put("product_detail",myara);
  }
}
catch (JSONException e)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

```
 public JSONObject getjsondataofcart(){
        JSONObject modelList = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray myara   = new JSONArray();
        String query = "select * from "+ cart_table;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

        try {

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    //Add this line here
                    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
                    data.put("id", cursor.getInt(1));
                    data.put("qty", cursor.getInt(2));
                    data.put("amount", cursor.getInt(7));
                    data.put("tax_id","0");
                    data.put("sub_total", cursor.getInt(6));
                    myara.put(data);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());

                modelList.put("product_detail",myara);
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
        }

        return modelList;
    }
```

Comment: thanks it working fine. its working exactly what i wanted